# Linker error with C++ function template instantiation (member function of template-instantiated class)

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have lots of **existing C++ code** with template classes that have implementations in the .cpp files. **I want to add a template function** to one such class. My problem is that I cannot **make the compiler instantiate** the function template.

I've created a stripped example demonstrating the problem. I want to add the member function `convert()`, with an own template parameter `LenNew`:

```
template <typename Number, int Len>
class MyClass {
public:
    // the function I'm trying to add
    template <int LenNew>
    MyClass<Number, LenNew> convert();

    // other methods I want to keep this way
    void function(); // implemented in .cpp file

private:
    Number n[Len];
};
```

In the existing setup, the .cpp file implements methods and instantiates the class template:

```
template <typename Number, int Len>
void MyClass<Number, Len>::function()
{
    // implementation
}

// instantiate template-class with specific template parameters
template class MyClass<double, 1>;
```

So I added the implementation for my new member function, and **tried to instantiate the template**, which doesn't seem to work:

```
template <typename Number, int Len>
template <int LenNew>
MyClass<Number, LenNew> MyClass<Number, Len>::convert()
{
    // implement...
}

// try instantiate
template<> template<> MyClass<double, 2> MyClass<double, 1>::convert<2>();
```

It compiles fine, but I get an undefined reference when I try to use `convert()` from a different .cpp file:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `MyClass<double, 2> MyClass<double, 1>::convert<2>()'
```

Here is a **Gist with the demo program**: https://gist.github.com/md2k7/8503385

Sorry, there seem to be a lot of very similar questions, but I could still not grasp what is wrong.

Comment: You cant have the implementation of a template in cpp, it has to be in .h

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't think up the setup with the files; is it impossible to add the template function as I want to?

Comment: The template definition must be in the same compilation unit as where it is instantiated. That's why you need to have it in a header file. You can't link against class/function-templates in other compilation units. My suggestion would be to manually fetch the definitions from other cpp files and put them in header-files for reuse.

Comment: "The template definition must be in the same compilation unit as where it is instantiated.": yes. `myclass.cpp` has the template definition and instantiates the template.

Comment: "You can't link against class/function-templates in other compilation units.": The (instantiated) class template stuff (i.e. `MyClass<Number, Len>::function()` with `<double, 1>`) is linked correctly with the pre-existing code. Just my new function template `convert()` doesn't link.

Comment: @Borgleader What about [explicit instantiation](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1C75fSEw/)?

Comment: @Constructor What about it?

Comment: @JorenHeit Linking against templates in other compilation units is possible if explicit instantiation is used.

Comment: @Borgleader This mechanism allows to have the implementation of a template in cpp.

Comment: It only functions if you know in advance what the parameters will be and export those instantiations. You cannot export a template- only an instantiation of it.

Comment: @DeadMG Of course you are right. But this question is about exactly such case as I understood.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I'm just saying that your language is a bit confusing here. The feature is called "extern templates", and you can only export an instantiation, not a template.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm sorry for my language. It is extremely bad, I know. It is difficult for me to explain what I really mean.

Comment: @DeadMG But extern templates is a slightly different feature, it is useful if class/function template definitions are located in `*.h` file, not `*.cpp`.

Comment: @Constructor yes, explicit instantiation is what I meant to use (see Constructor's answer for the correct syntax for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to explicitly instantiate the method of the class template. And this method is also template. You are trying to use such construction for it:

```
template<> template<> MyClass<double, 2> MyClass<double, 1>::convert<2>();
```

But this construction means something quite different. It is a declaration of explicitly specialized method template of non-specialized class template. There is right construction in your case:

```
template MyClass<double, 2> MyClass<double, 1>::convert<2>();
```

But you also should add an instruction for extra explicit instantiation of `MyClass` class template:

```
template class MyClass<double, 2>;
```

if you really want to use the result of `convert` method in your code.

Comment: I almost had it and then messed up the syntax... Thank you, this is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a **workaround - specialize** the new member function `convert()`, explicitly putting the correct version in `myclass.cpp`:

```
template <>
template <>
MyClass<double, 2> MyClass<double, 1>::convert()
{
    // implementation...
}
```

This might lead to some duplicated code for `convert()`, as it is needed for every version of `MyClass<Number, Len>` (but for me, currently only 2 versions will need to have this function), but the old code can stay the same.